# vb.net - How to set DataSet as source for Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a listview, a combobox, and a crystal report viewer.

When I choose from the combobox, it will filter the database and add the items in the listview.

What I want to do is to transfer the listview items to the crystal report viewer.

I tried putting the listview items first into a datatable and set the datatable as datasource of the crystal report viewer, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub cmbGetClass_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'populate the listview
        showSched()

        dtClass.Rows.Clear()
        With dtClass
            For row As Integer = 0 To lvSched.Items.Count - 1
                For col As Integer = 1 To lvSched.Columns.Count - 1
                    .Rows.Add((lvSched.Items(row).SubItems(col).Text))
                Next
            Next
        End With

        crViewer_Class.ReportSource = dtClass
        crViewer_Class.RefreshReport()
        crViewer_Class.Show()
End Sub
```

PS. I'm putting the items in the listview to a certain location(row and column) that's why I'm putting them like this in the crystal report. Hope you can help me, thanks!

EDIT: It doesn't have any error in code, but it doesn't show any data in the crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    crViewer_Class.SetDataSource(dtClass)
```

instead of

```
    crViewer_Class.ReportSource = dtClass
```